# Haystack's ElasticsearchDocumentStore() cannot connect running ElasticSearch container

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, ssl, haystack

I am using ElasticSearch version 8.5.1 and the latest python library of ElasticSearch concurrent with version 8.5.1. Also, my Python version is 3.10.4. I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vwq7Ucp9UCw&list=PLIUOU7oqGTLixb-CatMxNCO-mJioMmZEB&index=5) but clearly some of the software have changed a few things over the past year.

I am having trouble with Haystack's `ElasticsearchDocumentStore`. After following the ElasticSearch instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) for deploying an instance of a single node in a container using a docker image, I was able to run the following 2 code blocks successfully:

```
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection
    
    client = Elasticsearch( [{ 'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 9200,'scheme': 'https'}], 
    ca_certs="../http_ca.crt", http_auth=('username', 'password'))
    resp = client.info()
    resp  # this executed correctly
```

and this just for good measure:

```
    r = requests.get('https://localhost:9200/_cluster/health', verify="../http_ca.crt", 
    headers={"Authorization": 'Basic ' + TOKEN})
    r.json()  # this executed correctly
```

Then I tried

```
    from haystack.document_stores.elasticsearch import ElasticsearchDocumentStore

    doc_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
        host="localhost",
        port=9200,
        scheme="https",
        username = "username",
        password = "password",
        index = "doc1",

)
```

and no matter what I try above, I get this error:

> Output exceeds the size
> limit.
> Open the full output data in a text
> editor
> WARNING:elasticsearch:GET https://localhost:9200/ [status:N/A
> request:0.029s] Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 386, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 1042, in *validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py",
> line 414, in connect
> self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(   File "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
> ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(   File "c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py",
> line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
> return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 512, in wrap_socket
> return self.sslsocket_class._create(   File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
> self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ### Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> self.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)
> Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
>
> ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
> File c:\Users\k.mufti\Desktop\QA_system.venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\document_stores\elasticsearch.py:272, in ElasticsearchDocumentStore._init_elastic_client(cls, host, port, username, password, api_key_id, api_key, aws4auth, scheme, ca_certs, verify_certs, timeout, use_system_proxy)
> 271         if not status:
> --> 272             raise ConnectionError(
> 273                 f"Initial connection to Elasticsearch failed. Make sure you run an Elasticsearch instance "
> 274                 f"at `{hosts}` and that it has finished the initial ramp up (can take > 30s)."
> 275             )
> 276 except Exception:
>
> ConnectionError: Initial connection to Elasticsearch failed. Make sure you run an Elasticsearch instance at `[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}]` and that it has finished the initial ramp up (can take > 30s).
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In [97], line 1
> ----> 1 doc_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
> 2     host="localhost",
> 3     port=9200,
> 4     scheme="https",
> 5     username = "username",
> 6     password = "password",
> 7     index = "aurelius",
> 8
> 9 )
> ...
> 278         f"Initial connection to Elasticsearch failed. Make sure you run an Elasticsearch instance at `{hosts}` and that it has finished the initial ramp up (can take > 30s)."
> 279     )
> 280 return client
>
> ConnectionError: Initial connection to Elasticsearch failed. Make sure you run an Elasticsearch instance at `[{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}]` and that it has finished the initial ramp up (can take > 30s).

Any ideas or solutions? I have tried with and without the parameters that the function can take, and nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I simply forgot to add in the parameter `ca_certs="../http_ca.crt"` after copying the security certificate from the container onto the local machine.

```
doc_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
    host="localhost",
    port=9200,
    ca_certs="../http_ca.crt",
    scheme="https",
    username = "username",
    password = "password",
    index = "doc1"
```

If you installed ElasticSearch on your local machine and did not use a docker container as I did, then I am not sure where to get the certificate file from, but I imagine this process should be easier.

Comment: Hi! I am new to elasticsearch and got exactly the same problem here cannot figure out how to add. Could you please tell the solution in detail if possible? Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I have updated the answer slightly and I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you a lot! With the same error info, my problem have solved when I ran the Elastic version 7. It seems like currently Haystack cannot handle version 8. or over.(If that can help someone else:)

Answer (score 0):

After checking the process you did before you asked the question, I figured out that you need to add the certs file path to the haystack elastic store connection too.
After digging through their [documentation](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/document-store-api#elasticsearchdocumentstore) on the elastic search document store, I found out that you can do this.

```py
document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
    host="localhost", username="elastic",
    password="***", index="document",
    scheme="https", ca_certs="./http_ca.crt"
)
```

You need to use `https` as the scheme because after following the process of [installing elastic and kibana with docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) from the main documentation. The ip address uses ssl (https).

As for the `ca_certs`, this is the

> Root certificates for SSL: it is a path to certificate authority (CA) certs on disk - [ElasticSearchStore Haystack](https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/reference/document-store-api#elasticsearchdocumentstore)

The [ElasticSearch docker installation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html) specifies how you can get the cert file.

```bash
docker cp es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .
```

That copies the `http_ca.crt` file to the directory where you ran the command. So when you are providing the `ca_certs` field in `ElasticsearchDocumentStore` you will provide the path to the file. For my example, it is in the directory where I ran the program.

This is also a [github issue](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/issues/17) that addresses some of the issues you might encounter.